# Can we use Angular 2's server-side pre-rendering in place of server templating engine?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, frontend, templating-engine

I am a student, and still very new to web development. Recently, I have come across angular 1.x, react.js, and angular 2 (Ultimately decided to land on angular 2).

One thing that have hung in my mind lately is server-side pre-rendering. In my thought, this server-side pre-rendering is doing the job of server template processor (Like jade.js. I haven't tried it though). The difference is that the js templating code can be reused on client-side. Is my understanding correct? Does it mean that we can use angular 2 or react in place of other templating engines?

Comment: Could you look at Angular2 Universal already working with server side rendering, could you found more information about that on the following angular github https://github.com/angular/universal or video information https://angularu.com/VideoSession/2015sf/angular-2-server-rendering

Comment: Thanks, diegochavez. That github is new to me. Definitely going to try it.
I took a quick look on those, but still a little bit unsure. Can server-side pre-rendering replace template processing? I feel like they are similar, and server-side pre-rendering also allows us to reused the javascript on client's browsers. So there is no longer any need for template engine. What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

Angular 2's server-side rendering isn't replacing a templating engine.

Server-side rendering lets you write your Angular 2 code as you normally would (with or without something like jade). The server renders the first page the user will see, so the user isn't looking at a blank page while the javascript loads.  This decreases perceived page load times and makes the site more accessible to web crawlers.

[This video](https://youtu.be/MtoHFDfi8FM?t=9m49s) shows how you would implement server-side rendering in Angular 2.  There are some links to starter repos in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2 Universal is the server rendering project that is developed PatricJS and Jeff Wepley. Here is the maintained project in git.
It's a starter seed for new comers.

[Here (SystemJS)](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/tree/systemjs)

[For WebPack](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/)

For usage:

```
git clone https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/
git checkout systemjs
```